# HTML Paste Clipboard Image to File Input

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, here it goes. I have seen the great ways in which one can now paste images to WhatsApp web chats. Most examples use a canvas to capture the pasted clipboard image, how does one paste it to a File Input **using only Ctrl + V anywhere on the page**?

Here is the code I have for the input which automatically submits as soon as someone selected a file:

```
      <form id="new_document_attachment" method="post">
            <div class="actions"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" /></div>
                <input type="file" id="document_attachment_doc" />
      </form>
      <script>
          document.getElementById("document_attachment_doc").onchange = function() {
          document.getElementById("new_document_attachment").submit();
        };
      </script>
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. Just catch `paste` event on `window` object and put all the files you got from it to the `<input>` tag.

```js
const form = document.getElementById("new_document_attachment");
const fileInput = document.getElementById("document_attachment_doc");

fileInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
  form.submit();
});

window.addEventListener('paste', e => {
  fileInput.files = e.clipboardData.files;
});
```

```html
<form id="new_document_attachment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="actions"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" /></div>
  <input type="file" name="document_attachment_doc" id="document_attachment_doc" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! Brilliant!

Comment: For reference, in case you're wondering, this is supported in all major desktop and mobile browsers according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData

Comment: Also jquery equivalent is `e.originalEvent.clipboardData.files`.

Comment: I tried pasting from macOS' "screenshot to clipboard" function. This returns an `{"error":"key missing: title"}` message. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add that for the above example code to work I actually had to add enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute to the form element.

Comment: What browser were you using. I have been using the suggested answer for years now without issue

Comment: Firefox. It's just that it seems that multipart/form-data enctype is required when uploading a file. At least as per: https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_form_enctype.asp: "multipart/form-data  No characters are encoded. This value is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control". Perhaps Chrome silently switches to the required enctype or something?

Comment: Tested now on Edge 115.0.1901.203 (latest stable) and my form also did not work without `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. It´s really interesting :)