# HTML Paste Clipboard File to File Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that uploads a CSV file into a server via form submission.
It is working well, but I need to support copy and paste of CSV file from the actual file location to the input element.

I tried to do this code from a stackoverflow answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50427897/9751944)

```js
const form = document.getElementById("new_document_attachment");
const fileInput = document.getElementById("document_attachment_doc");

fileInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
  form.submit();
});

window.addEventListener('paste', e => {
  fileInput.files = e.clipboardData.files;
});
```

```html
<form id="new_document_attachment" method="post">
  <div class="actions"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" /></div>
  <input type="file" id="document_attachment_doc" />
</form>
```

It is working on images. But when I try it on CSV and other files, I am getting an error saying that the clipboard does not have any content
ie.

[image: The first FileList and File are for the test image while the second one is for CSV]

The first FileList and File are for the test image while the second one is for CSV

Comment: I fear it is an OS limitation... When looking at my clipboard data on osX Finder>Edit>Show Clipboard all I see is the file name of non image/*  files. Same way, the default value that gets inserted by the event is the file's name. Whereas with an image, it's the image that gets pasted.

Comment: I see. Sad to hear that @Kaiido . Let us wait for other answers, maybe someone has a workaround or something in mind. Thanks anyways! :D

Comment: Just to confirm, it's a OS limitation. If you do the same on Slack or Telegram, they end up with same png. Too bad...